# Receivables/lend

Tags: phrase-requests

If I lend an amount of $100 to my friend, I can refer to the amount as *receivable*. Suppose she returns $100 (or $70) after one week, what should I call this amount? It is the "return amount which is borrowed"?

Comment: The *paid* amount. The *repaid* amount. The *returned* amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any money that is paid back to you is a **payment** or a **remittance**.

In terms of how the money is applied to the debt, it may be **principal** if it is against the amount originally borrowed, or it may be **interest** if it is part of the fee you may have charged your friend for the trouble of loaning the money.

Comment: What if I pay an amount which I borrowed from my friend? What should I call it ?

Comment: @Rauf - Speaking informally, you would be _repaying a loan_ from a friend.  This doesn't acknowledge any distinction between principal and interest, usually because there isn't any interest if your friend loaned you the money as a favour.  You would call the money given back to your friend a _repayment_.